# Producing an xarray with multi-dimensional non-dimensional coordinates

Tags: python-xarray

I want to work with EEG data in *xarray*. In particular, the data comes in the following format: channel x time. The channel dimension consists of 64 unique channel names, which in turn correspond to locations on the head (and therefore have 3D coordinates).

I'd like to create a `DataArray` that I can index using the channel names (e.g. "Oz"), but which also contains the 3D locations in some way (so that I could e.g. interpolate between locations, or plot them in 3D space).

In the [documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/multidimensional-coords.html), the following is mentioned:

> In this example, the logical coordinates are x and y, while the physical coordinates are xc and yc, which represent the latitudes and longitude of the data.

It seems to me that this is exactly what applies here: the "logical" coordinates are the channel names, but the "physical" coordinates are the 3d position.

But How do I create this?

Just as an example, this is some dummy data:

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

data = np.random.rand(64, 1024)
time = np.linspace(0, 1, 1024)
channel_names = [f"electrode {i}" for i in range(64)]
positions = np.random.randn(64, 3)  # x, y and z for each channel


data_array = xr.DataArray(
    data,
    dims=['channel', 'time'],
    coords={'channel': channel_names, 'time': time}
)
```

How do I incorporate positions as physical coordinates for the logical coordinate channel?

Thanks!